# Drawing inside a window doesn't redraw and smears

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, gdi+

I am trying to draw a rectangle around the window (the inside of the window, not outside), but the drawing smears and in some cases doesn't redraw.

I subclassed the HWND WndProc ( the code runs in the HWND process, of course ):

```
class SubClasser : NativeWindow
{
 ...
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x85: // WM_CPAINT
            case 0xf:  // WM_PAINT
            {
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                Rectangle r = GetWndRect(this.Handle);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
                Trace.WriteLine("WM_PAINT: "+r.ToString());
            }
            break;

            default:
                Trace.WriteLine("0x" + m.Msg.ToString("X"));
                base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
        }
    }
 ...
}

private Rectangle RECTtoRectangle(RECT r)
{
    return new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom);
}
private Rectangle GetWndRect(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    RECT r = new RECT();
    GetClientRect(hwnd, out r);

    return RECTtoRectangle(r);
}
```

As you can see in the code, I am redrawing the "rectangle" on WM_PAINT and WM_CPAINT, but its not enough:

- When I make the window larger (resize), the rectangle doesn't become bigger.
- When I make the window smaller (again, resize), the rectangle becomes smaller, BUT when I enlarge the window, the rectangle smears until its original size (not larger).
- When I get the window outside the visible screen, part of the rectangle (only the bottom) doesn't get redrawn.

I should point out that I do get the paint messages and it seems that the subclassing works.

I am REALLY stuck :-(

EDIT:

OH, I also tried placing:

```
base.WndProc(ref m);
```

only at the end of the WndProc, got the same results.

Comment: What happens exactly in `GetWndRect`?

Comment: Your task sounds more like [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055(v=vs.85).aspx). Read [Using the WM_PAINT Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145193(v=vs.85).aspx). there are many GDI details you are 'skipping', like the `BeginPaint()`/`EndPaint()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to kennyzx and Fratyx answers I got to a working solution.

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case 0x85: // WM_CPAINT
            case 0xf:  // WM_PAINT
            {
                g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
                Rectangle r = GetWndRect(this.Handle);
                g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
                Trace.WriteLine("WM_PAINT: "+r.ToString());
            }
            break;

            case 0x05: // WM_SIZE
            {
                InvalidateRect(this.Handle, IntPtr.Zero, true);
                Trace.WriteLine("WM_SIZE");
            }
            break;

            default:
                Trace.WriteLine("0x" + m.Msg.ToString("X"));
            break;
        }
    }
```

Notice base.WndProc is at the beginning, because I must let the application draw first, and then I need to draw so I will be on top.

Comment: Don't forget to [`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromhwnd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) afterward, preferably via a `using` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as I can not test it and don't know the background of the member variable `g` but I think it's a problem with the clipping rectangle. So you could try something like this in your `WndProc` function to be sure that the entire window is redrawn:

```
case 0x05: // WM_SIZE
  InvalidateRect(this.Handle, GetWndRect(this.Handle), TRUE);
  break;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't call `base.WndProc(ref m);` more than once on a message;

Second, `g` should be recreated every time window size is changed, so it can draw on a bigger surface.

Third, call `Invalidate` on the window to force a redraw whenever window size is changed. I use the `SizeChanged` event and `ClientSize` since I can get the code compiled easily (need to read the documentation to write the GDI+/WINAPI stuff).

```
public partial class RedrawInWndProcForm : Form
{
    public RedrawInWndProcForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        p = new Pen(Color.Red, 2.0f);
        this.SizeChanged += (s, e) => { this.Invalidate(); };
    }


    Graphics g; 
    Pen p;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case 0xf:  // WM_PAINT
                {
                    g = Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle);
                    Rectangle r = GetWndRect(this.Handle);
                    g.DrawRectangle(p, r);
                    Trace.WriteLine("WM_PAINT: " + r.ToString());
                }
                break;
        }
        Trace.WriteLine("handled");
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private Rectangle GetWndRect(IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        return new Rectangle(0, 0, (int)this.ClientSize.Width, (int)this.ClientSize.Height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If drawing a border is all that is needed, then can we have a simpler mechanism as below?

1. Set redraw on resize to be true.
2. Override `OnPaint`

Example:
Assuming that the window you are sub-classing is a `Form`,

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true); // this is important
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Rectangle rcBorder = e.ClipRectangle;
            rcBorder.Inflate(-10, -10); // just to accentuate with red colored border
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rcBorder); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'm subclassing a native window (any given window)

Comment: Apologies, I totally missed it!